# Why doesn't my engineer count increase?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I've completed several missions that supposedly rewarded me with 4 engineers, but the engineer count (as shown in the Engineering display) hasn't increased. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, what you are telling seems right. Engineers and scientists are awarded immediately after the mission. When you enter Engineering or Research after the mission, you can also hear the head of the division thanking you for new people.

If you are sure you choose the Engineers mission and that the number stays the same, it is a bug.

P.S.: *There is an upsetting number of times I write "then this is a bug" in my answers* :-(

Comment: Ugh, that's what I'm worried about. And I'm sorely lacking in engineers.

Comment: Try a quick restart - start an easy game (probably without a tutorial, I do not remember if it will get in the way), run through intro mission, fast forward to the first abducition and check... If it works, you'll probably be better off restarting.

Comment: Looks like it may have been a bug—after a few missions, I started getting the engineer reward from ones that gave it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you choose the mission using the arrow keys?  The arrow keys cycle through the missions and their rewards, but only a click actually selects them.  I missed out on my desired reward a couple of times before realizing what was happening.

Comment: Well, I selected the mission, went on it, and completed it. Is there something else I'm supposed to be doing?

Comment: Will test. Creating an easy game now.

Comment: I did not reproduce the mismatch between displayed mission bonus and awarded one using arrow key shenanigans. Actually, this is unrelated to the question, because a tag says OP is playing on Xbox, and we test on PC - but I still tested.